# Do I need "Continue Shopping" button on the shopping cart?

Tags: buttons, user-expectation, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I did read a lot about **shopping cart page** this week and everywhere people insist to say:

- **Add continue buying button** on your basket to reduce the abandonment.
- The button "continue shopping" is an absolutely required button.
- Bla Bla Bla...

**BUT** I always think before clicking on this button when I'm buying: Where this button will take me? I think that is always a surprise because is too generic. And I never click there, I prefer to navigate using the browser back button to back the product page or make a new search or use the menu.

**Am I crazy?**

Why not:

- Back to the last product page button
- Go home and continue shopping
- A warning saying: Please, use the search bar or our amazing and very organized menu to continue buying
- None os this and just show related and frequently bought together products

**What's the best alternative? Why?**

Comment: Start with the use cases as to why a user will go to the shopping cart in the first place. Then figure out if it's necessary.

Comment: Question: how does your site's flow work? When someone adds an item to the cart, does it take them to the cart page?

Comment: @Majo0od No, we show a lightbox with go to the basket or continue shopping but the most part of people just closes the alert. And at the moment we are rethinking in the whole process and tracking every user behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best 2 solutions that I found until the moment are:

- Show 3 options for continue buying
- Show last seen products in a row

See the print screens

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't want to buy something in the same product category, with that purpose I would take the user to the front page (that should be the one that let me see the general categories).

If you are really buying objects on the same category, there are other alternatives before clicking to the "continue shopping" button, for example:

"The users that buy this usually also buys this X".

So, having that solved I really understand that you are saying, maybe you lose a customer when they are almost checking out. But even for that there are solutions, like send an email reminding what you have in your cart, offering discounts to end the process... things like that.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks for your points. To understand: You are suggesting to show frequently bought together and continue button lead the user to the homepage or some top-level category page? If yes, my question is: Why I need to continue shopping if the user can click on menu and user search bar on the header? And how user nows where the CS button will take him? Unfortunately, my user is once buyer, then nobody is logged in to get the emails and try to sell abandoned carts.